# My project wound up having two vastly different branches in git - is a git merge even possible or worth it?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

For my company's iOS app, which is currently on the App Store and being used, we decided to make and move to a completely new API.

So I forked the `master` branch into a branch I named `legacy`, with the idea being that bug fixes for the live app would just be performed on `legacy` as need be and all the new work, which included a fair amount of refactoring and renaming, would be in the `master` branch.

Some of you may see where this is headed already.

For various reasons the new API for the app got delayed. However, interest in the current app grew and as a result several things got added to the current app (so, the `legacy` branch) that do not currently exist in the `master` branch. And vice versa, since one of the goals of the new API was to add things that were not in the original.

So what I've wound up with is two branches, with the `legacy` branch both several hundred commits behind *and* ahead of `master`.

The new API is moving forward so I finally have the opportunity to merge everything into one big code base. The new API will be a superset of the old one so that part's covered but while my instincts are just to manually handle "merging" the two branches, treating them like separate code bases, I also know git was designed for merging. Yet I can't imagine this is within the parameters of what the designers had in mind.

If I've wound up with two branches that are essentially two divergent codebases, is it even possible to merge things with git or would it be better to, in this case, just suck it up and do it by hand?

Answer (score 2):

Git has many merge strategies that you can apply.  They are described in the link below, however there is no clear cut way for Git to merge on arbitrary code bases.  It still requires someone to merge manually when the merges are complex enough.  Given the complexity of the merge operation that you are describing I would think it would be better for you to merge manually.  You might be able to get away with having GIT do some of it.

https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies

Comment: As I wrote the question it occurred to me that maybe the best thing to do first would be to go apply some refactoring to the legacy branch to make it align with the master branch a bit better and then figure out a merge strategy, which might still wind up being essentially manually.